# Willl Azure Blob Direct WebURL work for distributing Files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cdn

The Azure CDN gives 404,But the direct web URL to the blob is working, can I use this to publicly distribute files. I have set Container access to Public.

Comment: Can you use what to publicly distribute the files?  The CDN URL or the blob URL?  If the CDN URL is returning 404 then obviously you can't use that to distribute files.  You could use the direct blob URL, but depending on your client access pattern this may not be a good idea.  If you are getting 404 from CDN then you likely have something configured incorrectly.  Since the files are public, can you provide the actual URLs?

Comment: @kwill Yeah,But not publicly.Could you give your email address.The CDN had worked earlier,but now it gives a 404,so its not misconfiguration its a technical glitch.